# How to set up shadowsocks server on a remote server which only occupy a port of an ip?

Tags: ssh, server

I have a ubuntu server, but  I have to connect to by `<ip>:8820`. I want to setup a shadowsocks server on it on port 1081, then how to connect to it? Say something like `<ip>:8820:1081`(which is invalid)? I have tried to use ssh to map it's 1081 port to my 1081 port:

```
ssh -N -f -L localhost:1081:localhost:1081 -p 8820 user@<ip>
```

Then I config my sslocal as:

```
{
    "server":"127.0.0.1",
    "server_port":1081,
    "local_address":"127.0.0.1",
    "local_port":10081,
    "password":"password",
    "timeout":300,
    "method":"rc4-md5",
    "workers":1
}
```

But it doesn't work, how can I do?

Answer (score 0):

First, **`Server ip`** must be your vps ip adress. And use 443 port(or othders but now GFW has upgrade to use whitelist, 443 port temporarily safe)

Second, Could you share your `ss-local.log` on here ?

If your `method:rc4-md5` doesn't work, you can try `aes-256-cfb`. I also have problems with the service on `method:rc4-md5`

Don't forget restart your `ss-server`.

Finally, Make sure your internet don't has any othder proxy.

Answer (score 0):

You don’t actually need that.

```
{
    "server":"0.0.0.0",
    "server_port":<your server port here>,
    "password":"password",
    "timeout":300,
    "method":"rc4-md5",
    "workers":1
}
```

Configure `ss-server` to listen on ‘0.0.0.0’.
Mapping remote port, simply you can use `ss-tunnel` instead.

Suggestions:
DO NOT USE STANDARD PORTS. (Random port number larger than 3000 smaller than 65536 is OK for me.)

The `rc4-md5` solution:
https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/issues/1966

Reference:
https://github.com/shadowsocks/shadowsocks-libev/blob/master/doc/ss-tunnel.asciidoc